# Fill TextBox by DataGridView data

Tags: vb.net, winforms

DataGridView1 will be filled by 1 line or 2 lines or 3 lines .. at most 5 lines .. and I have 4 columns
I want when I click on Button1 then TextBox from 1 to 20 will be filled by the data displayed on DataGridView1
TextBox from 1 to 4 will be filled by the first line
TextBoxes from 5 to 8 will be filled by the second line
TextBox from 9 to 12 will be filled by the third line
TextBox from 13 to 16 will be filled by the fourth line
The TextBox from 17 to 20 will be filled by the fifth line
For example .. if I have only 3 lines on DataGridView1 then in this case the TextBox from 13 to 20 will be empty.
When the 5 lines of DataGridView1 are filled I will have no problem but when I just have 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 line on DataGridView1 I will have a problem and it does not work.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles       Button1.Click
If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 2 Then
        TextBox9.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox10.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox11.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox12.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 3 Then
        TextBox13.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox14.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox15.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox16.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 4 Then
        TextBox17.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox18.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox19.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
 TextBox20.Text =DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are only going to have three rows, then you will need an IF-Then block to do something else for those extra TextBoxes.

Comment: sometimes I will have 1 line in my DataGridView1 so I will fill the TextBox from 1 to 4. sometimes I will have 2 line in my DataGridView1 so I will fill the TextBox from 1 to 8. sometimes I will have 3 line in my DataGridView1 so I will fill the TextBox from 1 to 12. Sometimes I will have 4 lines in my DataGridView1 so I will fill the TextBox from 1 to 16. Sometimes I will have 5 lines in my DataGridView1 so I will fill the TextBox from 1 to 20. when I click Button1

Comment: Um, ok.  Use an IF-Then block to see how many rows you have.  Pretty hard to figure out the problem here.

Comment: when I only have 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 line in DataGridView1 and I click on Button1 I will have this error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: Which is why you do an If condition.  Look at your last block with TextBox17-20:  Put `If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 4 Then` at the top of it.  Put an Else after it and set the four textboxes to an empty string.

Comment: sorry master .. I have not understood .. please if you can put this in my first code

Comment: You can edit your post above with any code update you have.

Comment: I could not edit my First code !!

Comment: Why not?  The edit link is under the tags above.

Comment: Yes master i edit my first code .. whis this code does not work

Comment: Index positions are zero-based, so Count = 4 would mean Rows.Item(3).  Confusing for a new programmer, I know.  Use > instead of = in those conditions.

Comment: 2 Questions 1. How is the DataGridView filled? 2. Why do you want to do this? Is the display in the DataGridView not adequate?

Comment: the DataGridView1 is filled by function Randomize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the code this way:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 4 Then
        TextBox17.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox18.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox19.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox20.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(4).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End If
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 3 Then
        TextBox13.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox14.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox15.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox16.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(3).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End If
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 2 Then
        TextBox9.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox10.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox11.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox12.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End If
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox6.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox7.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(1).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End If
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    End If
End Sub


Public Class TestItem
    Public Property Prop1 As String
    Public Property Prop2 As String
    Public Property Prop3 As String
    Public Property Prop4 As String

    Public Sub New(P1 As String, P2 As String, P3 As String, P4 As String)
        Prop1 = P1
        Prop2 = P2
        Prop3 = P3
        Prop4 = P4
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim source As New List(Of TestItem)
    source.Add(New TestItem("a", "b", "c", "d"))
    source.Add(New TestItem("e", "f", "g", "h"))
    source.Add(New TestItem("i", "j", "k", "l"))
    source.Add(New TestItem("m", "n", "o", "p"))
    'source.Add(New TestItem("q", "r", "s", "t"))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = source
End Sub
```

Do not mistake `Count` property with the `Rows`' collection `Index`, wich is 0-based. In you code you are checking if `DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0` and then access `DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0)`. If `Rows.Count` is 0 then `Rows.Items(0)` does not exists as it would be the first line but since the rows count is 0 there are no lines in the grid.

Comment: Thank you A.Buonanni.but it work only if DataGridView1 is completely filled by 5 rows.i tried with 4 rows i have this error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: I've tested the code, there's no error. How did you filled the DataGridView? I've edited my code providing a sample initialization of DataGridView1.

Comment: Thank you very much A.Buonanni for help.now it work perfectly.Cordially.SABRINE